# Reading through file one line at a time, running out of RAM

Tags: import, memory, streams

I have a handful of files (some of which are very large), and I would like to loop through them one line at a time, run a calculation, and then write the result of the calculation to a new output file:

```
Table[
file=OpenRead[fileName];
line=ReadLine[file];
While[Not[SameQ[line,EndOfFile]],
    newLine=ComputeSomething[line];
    WriteLine[outputFileName,newLine];
    line=ReadLine[file]];
Close[file],
{fileName,listOfFileNames}]
```

After running this code for a couple of days (on a system with 128GB of RAM) it crashes my system.  I get the following message:

```
No more memory available.
Mathematica kernel has shut down.
Try quitting other applications and then retry.
```

I'm trying to figure out what is eating up all of the memory.  The function `ComputeSomething[]` rewrites over all of its internal variables, so I don't think it can be that.  What I'm guessing is that I have the output file open the whole time, and as it gets larger I'm filling up my RAM?

Either that, or the results of `ReadLine[file]` get cached somewhere, and never actually  cleaned out.

Any suggestions to avoid this problem?

Also, a related question.  Is there a way to call a `ReadLine[]` type function, but specifying a line I want it to read (instead of just reading in the next line)?

Comment: Have you tried the `For` function to implement the loop?

Comment: Do you mean instead of the 'While' loop?  I haven't tried that.  Would you expect a 'For' loop to handle memory management differently?

Comment: I mean replacing `Table` with `For` saving memory.

Comment: @PleaseCorrectGrammarMistakes that is _never_ a good idea. Use `Do` instead of `For` in all situations.

Comment: @pl Using `For` or `Do` instead of `Table` won't save memory, I'm afraid. `Table` is essentially a loop, and the output of `Table` almost counts nothing in this case. Then, it's hard to give more advice without a minimal example that reproduces the issue, so I'm voting to close this question.